# update selected option value in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, sql-update

I have tabel with one of the data is fetch from another tabel. In this tabel, i used the id from the data to call it. But when i want to edit the data, it can't selected like the first data, it selected the next data.
What should i do? If i want edit the data, it can selected like the first data.
This is my code to select it :

```
    <select name="id_nasabah" id="nasabah">
    <?php 
      $query_nasabah = "SELECT * FROM nasabah";
      $hasil_nasabah = mysqli_query($conn,$query_nasabah);
      while($data_nasabah=mysqli_fetch_array($hasil_nasabah)){
         if ($data_nasabah == $id_nasabah) {
            $select = "selected";
         }else{
            $select = "";
         }
                                                
         echo "<option $select>".$data_nasabah['nasabah']."</option>";
      }
    ?>
    </select>
```

thats the tabel :

[image]

and thats the problem :

[image]

see, it selected the next option :

[image]

and this the database from tabel "nasabah" :

[image]

the $id_nasabah is from here :

[image]

can anyone help me?

Comment: Could you please update your question to show where `$id_nasabah` is getting its value? Thanks.

Comment: that wes updated, thank you @wayneOS

Comment: than i suspect `$id_nasabah` is holding the value of your table-column `nasabah`. I this case you need to change `if ($data_nasabah == $id_nasabah)` to `if ($data_nasabah['nasabah'] == $id_nasabah)`, because `$data_nasabah` is an array.

Comment: i follow your code, but the selected data is "pertamina". still the another data, not the first data before @wayneOS

Comment: Then please put `var_dump($id_nasabah);` and `print_r($data_nasabah);` in your code and udpate your question with the output. I need to see why the if-condition fails. Thanks

Comment: nothing happened @wayneOS